# Can not find Solr in HDP 2.3

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

I have installed HDP2.3 but can not find Solr while trying to add service
in admin panel under version I can see the HDP version as HDP-2.3.0.0-2557 but cnt find solr while trying to add service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr is no longer a service in the HDP stack. Instead it is an addon that can be downloaded from the HDP-Utils repository and installed separately. Solr is now part of HDP Search, you can read more about it in the [HDP documentation.](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_search/index.html)

Comment: Thanks i have configured it now